# How to passing PHP CLI with custom argument mask

Tags: php

i wanna ask about run PHP via CLI with given parameter. yesterday i run some php script from CLI using parameter/argument, i wonder how to do that. since i cant see the code, so i search for it from google.

what i know until now

```
<?php
    if(count($argv) <= 1) die('please provide input'.PHP_EOL);

    echo "first input: $argv[1]".PHP_EOL;
    if(!empty($argv[2])) echo "second input: $argv[2]".PHP_EOL;
?>
```

run: `php cli.php param1 param2`

result:

```
first input: param1
second input: param2
```

when i miss input, the script will be error

run: `php cli.php param2 param1`

result:

```
first input: param2
second input: param1
```

my question is:
how to write code like this

run: `php cli.php --input2 param2 --input1 param1`

or: `php cli.php -input2 param2 -input1 param1`

result:

```
first input: param1
second input: param2
```

i already read 2 tutorial article and PHP docs `getopt()` but i still can't do it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track. Based on [getopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php) example 2 you can do:

```
getopt([], ['input2:','input1:']); 
//for longoptions or fill the 1st array for the shortoptions
```

Comment: thanks my bro. i will check it after i going home (still otw)